# Materialize autocomplete with id, data from sqlite, and validation

Tags: javascript, ruby, sinatra, materialize

I am creating my first sinatra based web app, utilizing materialize-stepper for my form & materialize for the rest front end basically.
I have a form taking user 2 user inputs, each user input has autocomplete. The data for the autocomplete comes directly from my db. I am trying to find a way to add a feature where the inputs from user can only be used and form can only be submitted if the input comes from the suggestion autocomplete data, and somehow add an ID so i can reference each result.

The id is needed because, the form takes an origin and destination of airports from my database and makes a request to get flights with that information, if the data being passed is not valid, i wouldn't get results. Later i need to add a feature where the user can add that flight if he wants to hi profile, y for that i need to make each flight "trackable"

This is the code responsible for the autocomplete data and initializing

```
//   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // initialize stepper
const flightStepper = document.querySelector('.stepper');
const stepper = new MStepper(flightStepper);
// initialize the autocomplete
const elems = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete');
M.Autocomplete.init(elems, {
   limit: 8,
   data: {
      // pulling all the airports from the database
   <%@airport.all.map do |airport|%>
      <% if airport.iata_code.split('-')[0].size > 3%>
      // "beautifying the autocomplete text for the user and verifying its length"
         "<%= airport.name%> ,<%=airport.iata_code.split('-')[0].chop %>": null,
         <% else%>
         "<%= airport.name%> ,<%=airport.iata_code.split('-')[0] %>": null,
         <%end%>
    <%end%>
    }});
</script>
```

My form is basic form, takes origin airport, destination, etc.

Thanks to anyone who tries to help me!

Comment: How comfortable are you hacking the source code of the autocomplete component? There are two problems you need to solve here, both of which I have done (via hacks) and there is no reason you couldn't use them together. First - we run a check on keyup - if that letter doesn't exist in `data`, we delete it. Not perfect UX, but stops the user from inputting a non-existent airport. Second, we amend the autocomplete image function - instead of passing an src to src, we pass an ID to data-src. This stops console errors (image not found), and then hide the image span. Let me know if this sounds good.

Comment: Im going to try it right now. Im fairly new to coding and node in general so I'll do some event listening research and try to find a way to get it. The only real issue I see is u use sqlite3 and i can't connect to the database through client side in js, so i will have to perhaps save the data somehow and iterate over it on input. Thanks. I'll try to get it working.

Comment: You won't need to access db on client side, the ID will be passed on the server side when you build `data`. Let me know if you'd like to see an example.

Comment: Im more focused on filtering user input to the be submitted if it's matching input from autocomplete. J have been at it for days stuck

Comment: Take a look at this, if this is what you mean then either you or I can write it up as an answer: https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/zYGrXjJ

Comment: Thanls @SeanDoherty, tried implementing it but didn't really work :/ perhaps u can catch my mistake

https://codepen.io/Nadav123/pen/jOqPazL

Comment: two errors, on line 17 `console.log(ac)''` (i just commented it out), and missing a bracket at the end ')'

Comment: The autocomplete works but i can still submit whatever Wether it matches the data or not, any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Quite a lot wrong with your code still. You've got a non existent selector for the input, plus you've moved the check inside the autocomplete function (this runs at the end of the process, when an option is chosen), and there's no event listener attached to the input (my example used jQuery). Also, you're referencing instances (plural) which is never declared in your example.

Comment: Here is a re-worked pen https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/QWNbodG. This is working, except in the scenario where the user chooses an option and then goes back and deletes some characters (why they would do this is another question). So, you could push all the airports into an array and check the input value against this when the continue button is pushed, and maybe trigger a popup and delete the input contents.

Comment: I read your code and it was exactly what i needed. Thank you so much. i just wonder what instance[0].count stands for and what is it used for? instance[0] would ve the first letter i assume in the autocomplete input, since instance is the variable for autocomplete, but what the [0].count is used for?

Thank you so much. you saved me a big headache.

Comment: Also, it seems like it wouldn't work for the second input (the arriving at) i tried adding changing it to querySelectorAll (but it wouldn't work) as well as making a new eventListener with unique new ID for arriving at, i assume it is because of the instance[0] but i don't really know

Comment: Instance[0] is just the first autocomplete. `const ac = document.querySelectorAll('.autocomplete')` returns an array of all autocompletes. So you could use instance[1] to deal with the second one, or, if you are initializing them separately via ID (rather than all at once with querySelectorAll), then you'd need to declare and init them individually. Like this: const outward = M.Autocomplete.init(outwardAc, {}); const inward = M.Autocomplete.init(inwardAc, {});